# How to synchronized getter and setter from Preferences?

Tags: java, synchronization, preferences

Using Java I am using `Preferences` to store some application data. I want to store the configuration in variables during runtime. But when I need to set a value, how can I implement synchronization?

This is just a very simple example to understand my question:

```
public class Configuration {

    private static Preferences preferences = Preferences.userRoot().node("nodeName");


    private boolean isDarkMode;

    public Configuration() {
        // Get boolean value or return false if it does not exist
        this.isDarkMode = preferences.getBoolean("DARK_MODE", false);
    }

    //User changes setting to dark mode and the program needs to set the value to store it
    //TODO How can I synchronize this method?
    public static void setDarkMode(boolean b) {
         preferences.putBoolean("DARK_MODE", b);
         this.isDarkMode = b;
    }

    public static boolean isInDarkMode() {
        return isDarkMode;
    }
}
```

For my understanding it is not correct to just write `synchronized` to getter and setter, is it? What is a valid solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences is thread-safe and can be accessed from multiple threads without the need to synchronize shared resources. You can call flush() on write to ensure that the changes are made immediately. Instead of creating a class member like isDarkMode, reference Preferences directly.

Comment: Well I thought it would be better to store them, because I thought that they were written into a file. Does the Java RE load the Preferences into RAM or not? EDIT: Just found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313179/should-i-always-use-the-java-preferences-api-get-method-or-load-them-into-memo). To make it short: The data is buffered and cached, there is no need to load like I tried!

Comment: From what I can tell if the implementation is FileSystemPreferences then yes, but on MacOSX i'm not certain. Edit; Awesome, good find :)

Comment: I looked into the MacOS class, it says, that there is caching and also synchronization, so it works on all OS.

Comment: So just to clear it up: i DO NOT need to write synchronized, because Preferences is synchronized, correct?

Comment: Correct, you do not need to.

Comment: That helped me a lot, because I was not satisfied with my solution, thanks!